# Java instance variables initialization order

Tags: java, initialization, instance

I am asking somethimng quite common in `Java`, but unfortunately I could find an answer or a resource presenting a complete structured answer to this issue. I would like to know what is the complete process of the initilaization (of an Object) in Java and what is its order? In paticular I am not sure when the instance variables obtain their default values and their values of the initilization. As far as I know the inititialization order in a typical class i.e. `A` is:

```
class B {

}

class A extends B {

    int x = 5;

    public A() {
        ...
    }

}
```

1) static initialization block (provided that it exists)

2) call `super()` constructor

3) instance initilization block  (provided that it exists)

4) excecute the rest of the constructor

In which point in the above order does the default initiliazation (`x=0`) and the actual initialization (`x=5`) gets in the list?

Comment: There is no default initialisation in this code.

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Yes there is. `x` will have a value of 0 - at least notionally - while the superconstructor executes. A recent question suggests that some JVMs may optimize this away (violating the JLS, to my mind) but it's specified in the JLS.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Interesting, thanks!  However, isn't "notional" pretty important here?  (In the sense that whether or not this actually happens has zero observable effect on the program, I would imagine.)

Comment: @Oli It has consequences on the memory model.

Comment: @JonSkeet: After reading the docs, I infer that the initialization of the instance variables happens at the same time as instance initialiazation blocks. Moreover, the Example 12.5-2 makes it apparent that the variable x obtains the default value and it comes out when super() is called.